# Debugging anonymous session regarding cookie specific page caching

Tags: caching

Have been following this guide to make caching depend on the value of a specific cookie:

https://cornel.co/article/page-cache-cookiesor-anything-available-http-request-d9

However, it does not seem to work for anonymous users.

Debugging (xdebug) within both

**src/StackMiddleware/CookiesPageCache.php**

**src/CookiesPageCacheServiceProvider.php**

is possible when logged in as admin and running "cache rebuild" - but not when anonymous.

My question is - how should one go about debugging in the case of anonymous users?

Comment: You need two browser sessions, one logged-out for Xdebug and one logged-in to clear the cache (or use drush cr from the command line).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've done so, but xdebug is not triggered when running anonymous session which is what I need to work out why the caching is not working as hoped

Comment: "drush cr" is not doing any difference in regards of triggering the debug for anonymous users.

Comment: There is no question left to answer. Try different breakpoints, for example in index.php to see if XDebug is working. Look in the F12-tools of the browser to see the requests/response sent and received.

Comment: Thank you, I seem to be moving on now

Answer (score 1):

I know this is over a year later, but the reason you're seeing this for anonymous users is very likely due to having the core [Internal Page Cache module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/administering-a-drupal-site/internal-page-cache) installed, which caches and serves the complete response to all anonymous users, and part of that response are the cookies. I know this because I went down my own rabbit hole, pulling out my proverbial hair trying to figure out why this was happening, which I documented in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/neurocracy/drupal-omnipedia-menu/issues/1).